# How to generate a new list according to table rows in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, arraylist

I have a table which containes many columns , in case I can have 5 row or 6 rows n rows.
In my code I want to generate a list according to table's rows

For example I have car1 table which containes these elements :

Id ColumnName
1  Ford
2  Fiesta
3  Ford

For example I have car2 table which containes these elements :

Id ColumnName
1  Mercedes
2  BMW
3  Citroen
4  Renault
5  Kia

Each time when I executed code I have to create a generic list which consist of these tables elements .

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, why not make them all in the same table and call the ones you want by there place or id?

Comment: Actually I just need their name , I don't need table all , I am getting column names from table and creating a new list from a file , and these columns values becoming a title.So I am getting column names from table and getting value from a file reading all lines.After reading for example  BMW => 100 Mercedes => 250 Citroen => 300 Renault => 500 Kia => 2000 , so I hope I explained well , because there is another criteria which comes from file upload .

Comment: Then you can just make a string list that gets the names and with the names you can do everything you want, i beliave the answer post will help you, accept it if its what your looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
public void StudentList()  
{  
    //  DataTable dt = new DataTable("Branches");  
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Student");  
    dt.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(Int32));  
    dt.Columns.Add("StudentName", typeof(string));  
    dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));  
    dt.Columns.Add("MobileNo", typeof(string));  
    //Data  
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Manish", "Hyderabad", "0000000000");  
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Venkat", "Hyderabad", "111111111");  
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Namit", "Pune", "1222222222");  
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Abhinav", "Bhagalpur", "3333333333");  
  
    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();  
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)  
    {  
        Student student = new Student();  
        student.StudentId = Convert .ToInt32 (dt.Rows[i]["StudentId"]);  
        student.StudentName = dt.Rows[i]["StudentName"].ToString();  
        student.Address = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();  
        student.MobileNo = dt.Rows[i]["MobileNo"].ToString();  
        studentList.Add(student);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Maybe I express myself wrong , actually I want to create a list which consist of column name onbects, foreaxample I have a carlist 

        carlist.Add(new Carlist
                {
                    BMW=100,
                    Mercedes=200
                });

each time this carlist elements are changable , they can be another bran  , I hope I could explain

Answer (score 0):

//Generate Sample DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("car1");  
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
```

//Inserting Sample Data

```
dt.Rows.Add(1, "Mercedes");  
dt.Rows.Add(2, "BMW");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Citroen");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "Renault");
dt.Rows.Add(5, "Kia");
```

**This is the modern approach for creating a List in C#.**
For this example I am creating a simple car1 class like:

```
public class car1
{  
    public int Id{ get; set; }  
    public string Name{ get; set; }  
}



List<car1> carList = new List<car1>();
carList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows  
            select new car1()  
            {  
                Id= Convert .ToInt32 (dr["Id"]),  
                Name= dr["Name"].ToString() 
            }).ToList();
```

**Convert DataTable to List using a Generic Method**

```
private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)  
{  
    List<T> data = new List<T>();  
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)  
    {  
        T item = GetItem<T>(row);  
        data.Add(item);  
    }  
    return data;  
}
  
private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)  
{  
    Type temp = typeof(T);  
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();  
  
    foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)  
    {  
        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())  
        {  
            if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)  
                pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);  
            else  
                continue;  
        }  
    }  
    return obj;  
}

List<car1> car1Details = new List<car1>();  
car1Details = ConvertDataTable<car1>(dt);
```

Also see this - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/